# How do I import file B if file A does not exist?

Tags: javascript, file, ecmascript-6, import

I am wanting to create a config file containing environment variables. I don't want this file to be tracked by git so my solution is to create a default javascript config file e.g. `config.default.js` and have the other developers copy the contents of this file into a `config.js` file and modify the variables for their local environments.
The problem is if the `config.js` file does not exist yet when the import it to read the config file is run I get 'unable to resolve path to module' error. Is there a way to import `config.js` if it exists but import `config.default.js` if it doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple try{}catch(){} when you require the file.

```
try {

var myconf = require('./config.js');
} catch (error) {
var myconf  = require('./config.default.js');
}
```

Comment: The problem with this attempt is that bundling fails if `config.js` does not exist.

Comment: that depends on which bundling tool he uses. I think gulp tasks can handle a try catch.

Answer (score 0):

You could use fs module and check if configuration file exists and require accordingly.

```
let fs = require('fs');
let configFile = './config';
let defaultConfigFile = './config.default.js';
let myconf = null;

if (fs.existsSync(configFile)) {
 myconf = require(configFile);
} else {
 myconf = require(defaultConfigFile);
}
```